# Printf text and return value of a method call

Tags: haskell, printf

*Disclaimer: I am a total newb to haskell, but I can't find the answer. Maybe I am searching in the wrong way or it is so basic that nobody even asks that.*

Here is what I try to do:

```
import Text.Printf
factorial n = if n < 2 then 1 else n * factorial (n-1)

main = do
    let input = 22
    printf "Some text... %d! = %d" input (factorial input)
```

But that doesn't work, a bunch of errors appear. Can you give me a quick hint, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You do all right, but compiler can't infer type of an `input`, that's why you have many errors like `No instance for ...`

Comment: "a bunch of errors appear" -- please avoid to post that without reporting the actual errors. Further, `printf` is not very often used in Haskell -- use it only if you need special formatting. Otherwise, just use something simpler like `putStrLn ("x = " ++ show x ++ ", y = " ++ show y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler cannot infer the type of `input`. To do, you would need to provide it explicitly:

```
import Text.Printf
factorial n = if n < 2 then 1 else n * factorial (n-1)

main = do
    let input = 22 :: Integer
    printf "Some text... %d! = %d" input (factorial input)
```

Note that `Integer` willl work for very large results, whereas `Int` won't, quoting [Haskell Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/A_Miscellany_of_Types):

> "Integer" is an arbitrary precision type: it will hold any number no
>   matter how big, up to the limit of your machine's memory…. This means
>   you never have arithmetic overflows. On the other hand it also means
>   your arithmetic is relatively slow. Lisp users may recognise the
>   "bignum" type here.
>
> "Int" is the more common 32 or 64 bit integer. Implementations vary,
>   although it is guaranteed to be at least 30 bits.

Answer (score 2):

the only `input` is of ambiguous type in your code.

```
import           Text.Printf
factorial n = if n < 2 then 1 else n * factorial (n-1)

main = do
    let input = 22::Integer
    printf "Some text... %d! = %d" input (factorial input)
    return ()
```

Comment: That worked, than you. But now it is an int, the max size of it is limited. If I do this: print (factorial 22) instead, it does not seem to be an int because it shows the correct value instead of the int max size. Any idea?

Comment: my fault. It should be `::Integer`